# Seperation between navigation bar and table view disappear

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I am creating an app with a navigation bar and a table view. For some reason, the navigation bar lacks its separator between it and the table view. In the Interface builder, it looks like [it does have it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIXaR.png) However, when I run my app in the simulator (or on device), [the separator disappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmLh4.png) Why?

Edit: [Here's a better picture of my storyboard as per requested.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj0b5.png)

Comment: can you show a little zoomed out snapshot of your storyboard?

Comment: First delete that thing is not a navigation controller.You have to choose your first view controller and from top menu you must select `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller`  This is how you add Navigation Controller to a View Controller. Also you have to use delegation for passing data back from the pushed view controller.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer so you can close the question. @nintyapple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose your first view controller and from top menu you must select `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller` This is how you add Navigation Controller to a View Controller.

Also you have to use delegation for passing data back from the pushed view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the shadow image for the navigation bar? Like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ShadowImage"]];
```

If you set, try to remove.